# create tunnel in order to access https via port 443

Tags: linux, windows, http, port, tunneling

I have win machine that connected to Linux server **192.9.100.10**

And Linux server has connectivity to the IBM blade center management GUI - **192.9.100.200**

From my WIN machine I **not** have connectivity to **192.9.100.200**

My target is to access the IBM management center as **https://192.9.100.200:443**

So I do the following steps

I use the putty and create a tunnel from the Linux server to the IBM blade center management VIA port **443**

In the forward port in the putty I set that putty

```
     L1000               192.9.100.200:443
```

After this setting I verified the port 443 as the following from the cmd window ( on the WIN machine )

```
     telnet 192.9.100.200 443
```

and I get telnet connection successfully

but when I try to access the IBM management center by http as
https://192.9.100.200:443

the I not get any connection ( white screen )

can someone help me to understand what the problem here?

How to debug and how to resolve the problem?

- Remark - window firewall is enabled!

Comment: Do you have Java installed?

Comment: Java ? why this is relevant to my case?  ( I have on my XP win machine Java - 1.6.0_17 )

Comment: do you mean that I need to remove the Java from my XP machine ?

Comment: Many management interfaces use Java.  It's not necessarily a problem with your connection, but could be a problem with the management interface.  Some of the older management interfaces from IBM, HP, and EMC use Java.  If you don't use the right version of Java, you can't load the interface.  You should look up the management interface version and verify you're using the right version of Java first.  If your Linux and Windows system are on the same network, and only the Linux system is able to access the management interface, it leads me to believe it's not a network issue.

Comment: yes - I verified this and the java version , java 1.6.0_17 is fit for this case , what other things chuld be the problem ?

Comment: Browser compatibility, certificate problem, network routing problem or something else.  Need to rule out one by one.  Is the IP address supposed to be 192.9.100.200?  That's not a standard internal IP (and not a standard example of a correct internal IP); that's actually a real public IP.

Comment: hi , yes this is browser problem , I use explorer 6 and after I instaslled the firefox , its solve the problem , again thx - ,